# Extend a default JS component or Use Mixin

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.2.6, mixins

Which is better and recommended to use `Extend a default js component`  as explained at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html#extend_js or to use `Mixins` as explained at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html

What are the pros and cons of them?

How to decide which one to use?